# SQL Azure is recommending Indexes that are already on my Table

Tags: sql, azure, indexing, query-optimization, sql-optimization

In the Azure Portal you see recommendations from SQL Azure. The weird thing is that these indexes already exist on my Table.

A query on MemberId on the Tip table also returns within I <250ms on a table of 7.5 million records so I have the feeling the index is working.

We do seem having performance problems during high traffic. 
What could be going on?

[image]

**TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tip](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MemberId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Slot] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [PeriodKey] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [LastChanged] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Invalid] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ListingIndex] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Tip] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_Tip_Unique_Key] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [MemberId] ASC,
    [PeriodKey] ASC,
    [Slot] ASC,
    [ListingIndex] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tip] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Tip_Invalid]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Invalid]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tip] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Tip_ListingIndex]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ListingIndex]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tip]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Tip_Member] FOREIGN KEY([MemberId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Member] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tip] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Tip_Member]
GO
```

This is a really simple query on MemberId. Normal queries might be a bit more complicated:

[image]

This is the Index that it tries to create in the Azure portal:

[image]

Comment: Is the table partitioned? What is the full `CREATE TABLE` including indexes?

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith, the table is not partitioned. Is there an easy way to show the `CREATE TABLE` + indexes? I usually use the designer from Sql Management Studio.

Comment: Hi Martin, it's a bit of a guess because SMSS just shows me a seconds (can't find to see ms?). I've updated the answer with more information!

Comment: In the Azure portal can you click the `CREATE INDEX` and see the SQL that it proposes to run? Maybe the one it wants to create has additional included columns not present in your existing index

Comment: Is Azure sending you an email about performance degradation during high traffic? (Maybe from Application Insights, or something like that?) If so, there are probably links to "further information".

Comment: Hi Martin, Mike, I've updated with the Index that Azure tries to create.

Comment: So the one it wants to create contains at least two columns (Invalid,LastChanged) that is not included in the original index. Possibly other columns too that I can't see in the truncated screen shot. You could consider replacing the unique constraint with a unique index that has the same key columns but includes any additional columns needed. Or if that turns out to be basically all the columns whether you should make it the clustered index.

Comment: OMG, I never understood that 'Included columns' is actually a concept within SQL. So in theory I see that actually all columns are included in the suggestion. Does this actually mean it makes a whole 'copy' of the table, so it never has to go back to the original table while querying?

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith, if you write your comment in an answer I can upvote & accept it - might help other that never knew that you can include columns into an index that are not part of the index. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: I am seeing the same sort of behavior with Query Performance Insight - recommending indexes that are clearly already added and have been for 24hrs+, so not sure if I trust this feature or if its cache needs to clear etc.  I realize this question is over 5yrs old, but I didnt see another thread on it.